# How to get hyperlinks in BIRT report viewer

Tags: birt

Using BIRT 4.2

My database (Postgresql) has many fields with hyperlinks in it and when I am displaying the reports via BIRT report viewer, all the fields which have hyperlinks are displayed as normal text in the BIRT report viewer. I want the hyperlinks to be retained at the BIRT report viewer. How can I achieve this. Please suggest.

Comment: I am working on a drill down feature. Could you pls let me know how to set the URL from the document as I am using Hyperlink Drill Through option but while i ran the report on spagoBI server it is showing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the corresponding cell and go to the hyperlink property and click on edit and select the URI radio button and click on the javascript syntax button and you will find your column bindings from that select the value of the column and finally you  will get the hyperlinks[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, I could not achieve it with this,the entire column is now shown as links but when I click on it,it is redirecting with in the birt web application and it is looking for the value of the row. E.g if my test.rpt file is in birt war file,then when I click on the link, it is redirecting to http://localhost:8080/birt/webcontent/86067  where 86067 is row value which should point to the hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

your url should be like this **(http://www.+row["Title"]+.com)** if your Title field having google means then your string should be like this `("http://www.google.com")`.if you didn't append any HTTP means then it will look for the file which is in `webcontent` folder of your birt.war