# How to get hyperlinks in BIRT report viewer between two tables

Tags: report, birt

I have two separate tables and would like to establish link between one of the columns of the two separate tables. I tried various ways but I am not getting how can I establish link between elements of the two separate table. Any clue?

Best Regards,
Hemal Bavishi

Comment: Have you tried the solution proposed here?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193664/how-to-get-hyperlinks-in-birt-report-viewer

Comment: Problem is bit different from the link you have provided. I am able to create a bookmark for the static text and provide hyperlink but I am not able to create a link for the elements which are generated dynamically. For an example, I have two tables SystemSignalTable and ISignalTable. SystemSignalTable contains the element name as "SHORT-NAME" - Name of the System Signal. ISignalTable contains the element name as Reference to SystemSignalName. I want to establish link between two tables with the actual names generated in the table for that particular database but it's not generating hyperlink.